# Rails: Detecting user agent works in development but not production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to detect Blackberry user agents in my app, which works fine in my development version. But nothing happens when I redeploy the app in production.

application_helper.rb

```
  def blackberry_user_agent?
    request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(Blackberry)/]
  end
```

application.html.erb

```
<% if blackberry_user_agent? -%>
<div class="message">
<p>Using a Blackberry? <a href="http://mobile.site.ca/">Use the mobile optimized version</a>.</p>
</div>
```

I've tried clearing the cache using rake tmp:cache:clear and restarted mongrel a few times. Apparently the HTTP_USER_AGENT is coming back nil in production. I am using Nginx with a mongrel cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Apache or nginx in front of your mongrel(s)?

Are you logging the user_agent? This is from my nginx.conf:

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] $request '
                  '"$status" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

Comment: I am using nginx with a mongrel cluster.

Comment: can you post your nginx conf in a gist or a pastie?

Comment: I tried adding that to line 21 of the conf and restarted the server. Still not working, any other ideas?

Comment: All that line done it set the format for the log. Did you check the nginx logs to see what it's reporting as the user agent for the blackberry?

Answer (score 44):

Try:

```
request.user_agent
```