# How to make a webpage display differently in different browsers?

Tags: coding-style, browser

I want to display the contents of a web page in a different format in different browsers.
How to go about implementing it?

EDIT:More Information

The motivation behind this is to display the content in different mobile devices.
For example: iPhone uses Safari
So if a safari browser is used I will adjust the content so that it fits the screen of the iPhone perfectly and I can change the font size etc

If some other browser is used then I will change the format appropriately.

Comment: Do other browsers use less/more of the screen on mobile devices? How is this different from computer displays?

Comment: We need to eliminate scrolling sideways to see the information. We need to maximize the info that can be seen on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the contents of the User Agent header that is sent with the HTTP request. Until you tell us more about what you're using to display the page I can't be any more specific, but you should compare the User Agent header to known browsers and then serve up different content based on that test.

Comment: Except that header is not a reliable indicator of the browser.

Comment: @Rob, there *is* no reliable indicator of the browser. Browsers can pretend to be whatever they want. Heck, the browser could just be some guy typing at a terminal. The user-agent is simply the standard method of self-declaration.

Comment: @tioflin - Um. That's what I just said.

Comment: @Rob, OK. I was just clarifying because it sounded like you were saying that the user-agent header was not the most reliable indicator: that there was another, more reliable one I hadn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPhone')) {
        // is iPhone
    }
?>
```

Comment: And where did he mention iPhones?

Comment: @Josh Just took it as an example.

Comment: and based on his revised question you appear to be right! He didn't mention PHP either though.

Comment: I am indeed implementing this in PHP. Sorry for not being clear enough in the question

Comment: Here's a post that says how to do this sort of thing in Rails: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233802/rails-detecting-user-agent-works-in-development-but-not-production

Answer (score 0):

In addition to reacting on different `user-agent` HTTP headers, you can also use some CSS tricks to differentiate at least between IE and non-IE browsers, and different IE versions. And of course there is still another method: Use some JavaScript code to show/hide specific parts of the page depending on the browser detected from that JavaScript code.

As a rule, though, I would avoid any browser specific stuff and write the pages in a way that renders well in the most important browsers, and reasonably gracefully degrades with the older and ancient browsers.

Let me also note that if you decide to `user-agent` switching after all, please do make sure you fall back to reasonable defaults. Nothing is more annoying than needing to masquerade my browser A as browser B just because some web site does not know about browser A or something similarly stupid.

Answer (score 0):

Browse-sniffing is tricky to do because many user agents try to mimic others to get past programmer-induced restrictions. If you're specifically trying to make a mobile-friendly stylesheet, using the "media" attribute of the LINK tag is a good way to target specific devices. i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css" media="all"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" media="handheld"/>
```

The first stylesheet will be applied to all media types, while the second will only get applied to "mobile" devices.

If you're looking for a way to target only IE, check out Conditional Comments: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Aaaand for a bit more information on controlling the viewport of the iPhone, check out this article from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html